# Table View is now shown in simülatör swift/xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

hello i am new to learning swift. I want to save data in database and show it in tableview. But even though I do everything, the tableview does not appear in the simulator. white screen appears. Any idea about the reason? I looked at the previous questions but couldn't find an answer.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    //tanımlamalar
    var nameArray = [String]()
    var idArray = [UUID]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //tableview gösterme
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        //add butonu ekleme
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.add, target: self, action: #selector(addButtonClicked))
    }
    //verileri getirme
    func getData() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        //getirme
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName : "Paintings")
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        
        do{
            let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if let name = result.value(forKey: "name") as? String{
                    self.nameArray.append(name)
                }
                if let id = result.value(forKey: "id") as? UUID{
                    self.idArray.append(id)
                }
                //yeni veri eklenirse tableviewı reload et
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
    }
    //add butonuna tıklanırsa ne olacak
    @objc func addButtonClicked() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "DetailsVC", sender: nil)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nameArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        content.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.contentConfiguration = content
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not calling `getData()` so the table will be empty. Why are you using a plain `UIViewController` with your own table view instead of using `UITableViewController`?

Comment: i did but it didn't work